# Wireless keyboard pressing the command key by itself

Tags: keyboard

Recently, my Apple wireless keyboard has been pressing the command key by itself repeatedly. It's stuck like that until I turn off then on the keyboard.

Anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a hardware problem - you could try disassembling it and cleaning the contact layer.

Comment: If the keyboard in question is one of the newer chicklet/laptop-style keyboards, it cannot be disassembled as easily.

Comment: It's [this one](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B005DLDO4U/).